# Relation between $ \bigcap_{i \in I}A_i $ and $ \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let I be a nonempty set and a family of sets 
such that every element of the family is a subset of U.

$\mathcal F = \{A_i | i \in I\}$

I understand the meaning of this operation:

$$
\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i
$$

That's the intersection of all the elements of the sets of the family $\mathcal F$.

But I don't truly understand what this other operation means and what's the relation between the above one.
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i
$$

I understand that this operation is also an intersection but what I am trying to understand is the relation between $\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i$

$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i
\subseteq\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i
$$

Is the relation above true?

Comment: In the second case we have $I = \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $$\bigcap _{i=1}^nA_i$$ 
denotes the same as 
$$ \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$$
for the special case $I=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: So $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ is the general case and $\bigcap _{i=1}^nA_i$ is a specific case for which we give concrete values to i?

Comment: @adriana634 Yes. One situation where we see both notations used simultaneously is when $I=\mathbb{N}$; then "$\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i$" means "$\bigcap_{i\in \{1,2,..., n\}}A_i$," which is generally a *superset* of $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber But for example $\bigcap_{i=1}^{5}A_i$ means $I=\{1,2,\ldots, 5\}$, in this example  $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ is a superset of $\bigcap_{i=1}^{5}A_i$? I don't understand why you said $\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i$ is a superset of $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: @adriana634 No. The intersection over a *bigger* index set yields a *smaller* set. E.g. if we take $I=\mathbb{N}$ and $A_i=\{i, i+1, i+2, ...\}$ for $i\in I$, then $\bigcap_{i=1}^5A_i=\{5, 6,7,...\}$ but $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\emptyset$. More abstractly: $$I\supseteq J\implies \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in J}A_i.$$